# Distinguishing between different Activity transitions

Tags: android, lifecycle

I have an Activity that plays some audio from within a `ListActivity`. The user can also click on the list item and go to a more detailed view of that data. I want the audio to keep playing during that transition from one activity to another and keep playing once the detail activity is active BUT I also need to pause the audio if my activity is being paused or stopped for any other reason.

My issue is that I currently pause the audio in `onPause()` in the ListActivity because I want the audio to be paused when the user navigates away from my activity. E.g. when they press Home or Back. However, I don't want the audio to pause when my detailed view activity gets started. `onPause()` is called in both instances, so how can I distinguish between the two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be doing that in a [service](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components) instead? Wouldn't it be easier? Then you can stop the service when one or another activity is pausing or exiting (depending on which one you want). You could also check if it's started, and stop accordingly whenever you want.

Or sorry if I didn't understand your question. I see you have a lot of points here on SO, so perhaps I'm just confused.

--- edited since your third comment:

1. **A Intent to B**: send `Intent` with name of music.
2. **B onCreate**: get name of music from `Intent`. Set flag `x` to `true`.
3. **B onResume**: start playing music if from A *or* resumes from last known position if resuming from B.
4. **B back button**: override and set `x` to `false`. Actually, you'd cover all points where your activity `finish`es.
5. **B onPause**: stop the music `if(x)`, store last known position of music in memory and stop service.

Here I assume that you want music to keep playing even when returning to A (that's what you said, that's the problem), not just up to B. Setting x is important early on, IMO, because if any other activity (phone call, anything) appears, activity will stop playing the music immediately (user expects that) on onPause. According to Android guidelines, you know that you're getting back to A only if user presses back button or if you finish() your activity. You can fine tuning checking the position of activities in your task (don't remember how to do that right now).

Personally, I also wouldn't want to resume playback on A (say, B->call->home->A, applying step 3 to A, too), because a disruption in the logical flow of things happens there.

***CAVEAT***: I would make sure that there is no other way. I would try to see if you can 1) *know in advance which activity is about to be displayed*. 2) get any music service to hook up to your task (is that even possible?).

Anyway, just use my solution if you can't find a clever way to do that. That would be my suggestion. Good luck.

Comment: Not sure what a service would do for me here. I can already keep the audio playing between the activities, but I still need to be able to pause it when onPause or onStop is called for all but my transition to the details activity.

Comment: If you were confused by the question, others will be too. I edited to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: As far as I can see, you want the audio to be played: 1) when activity A or B is active; AND 2) have fine control if an item on your list is active (say, a music title). I believe that you can use both your onPause routines to flag a boolean to the service, and the service would stop playing everytime you have false on both (when none of the activities are running). You could also deactivate both when you unselect an item from the list... (...)

Comment: (...) The way I see, you're trying to guess from Activity A's onPause if you're about to see Activity B (in this case, keep playing) or if you're going somewhere else on the system (then stop playing). I don't know, maybe you can verify that from one onPause, but AFAIK, I don't think we can safely. Is that it? If it's not, then my guesses end here, and I wish you good luck.

Comment: You got it right. I want to keep playing as long as Activity A or B are active and stop otherwise. Passing a flag to the player is an interesting idea I'll play with, but I think Activity A's onPause is called before Activity B's onResume, so there would be that very short time when both are paused and the player would pause the audio too.

Comment: Hey, I updated my answer. I know that would work, but I'm very concerned about finding another clever solution for your problem. I suspect that one of the "caveats" above may apply to you. :-) Sorry if I couldn't help more.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for taking the time to really think about this problem. I'm doing something similar to what you described so I'll accept your answer. Basically, in Activity A's onListItemClick, if the clicked list item is currently playing, I set a flag immediately prior to the startActivity that goes to the details view. Then in onPause I only pause the audio if the flag is not set. Same for Activity B, except I set the flag in onBackPressed. Thanks again for the ideas!

Comment: Yeah, those steps are not carved in stone, I can think of many minor variations according to specific needs in the ListView etc. About me taking the time, nevermind, I wasn't really doing anything right now, so I'm glad I could help someone. Best regards.